# Ошибка с памятью в перегрузке оператора

Tags: c++, память

Есть вот такая перегрузка оператора ++ (постфиксная).

В `this`'е хранятся:

```
s="first"
length=5
```

Вот сам код:

```
String& String::operator++(int i)
{
    int n = this->length + 1;

    char* tmp = new char[n + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < this->length; i++)
        tmp[i] = this->s[i];

    tmp[n - 1] = tmp[n - 2];
    tmp[n] = '\0';

    this->length = n;

    delete[] this->s;

    this->s = tmp;

    return *this;
}
```

На `delete` вылетает ошибка записи памяти.

Comment: Какой символ должен добавляться к строке этим оператором, если исходная строка пустая? Из кода видно, что вы этого не учли. У вас опять строка будет пустой.

Comment: Имейте в виду, что постинкрементный оператор не возвращает ссылку на исходный объект.

Comment: Спасибо, учту. Я пока не делал проверку исключений

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну вообще, постфиксный инкремент по логике должен возвращать старое значение (строки), которое на самом деле должно являться копией. Больше не вижу ошибок в коде, но вылетать на delete может из-за того, как вы выделили s. Если она указывает на read-only memory, то это вполне логично.

Т.е. если начальное значение у вас присваивается как `this->s = "blabla"`, а не создается новый массив char и в него копируется ваша read-only строка **"blabla"**

Comment: Да, вы правы. Ошибка оказалось в операторе >>.

Comment: Вот что у меня получилось:
   ' istream& operator >> (istream& is,String& s)
    {
     char temp[256];
     is >> temp;
     s.s = new char[strlen(temp+1)];
     strcpy(s.s, temp);
     s.length = strlen(s.s);
     return is;
    }'

Comment: @Никита  В данном выражение new char[strlen(temp+1)]; вы неправильно вычисляете длину строки. Я думаю, вы имели в виду new char[strlen(temp) +1)];

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Конечно, это просто описка)

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка связана с неопределенным поведением программы. Видимо указатель `s`не содержит корректный адрес или содержит адрес памяти, которая не была выделена с помощью оператора new.. Причину ищите в других членах класса, где устанавливается или, наоборот, не устанавливается значение `s`.

Что касается самого оператора, то обычно постинкрементный оператор возвращает новый временный объект, равный исходному до его изменения, и изменяет исходный. То есть его объявление выглядит в общем случае как

```
T operator ++( int );
```

или

```
const T operator ++( int );
```

Что касается вашего класса `String`, то если исходная строка пустая, то она не изменяется, так как в строке еще нет символов, чтобы использовать последний из них в качестве символа-заполнителя (Другой подход - это использовать в качестве заполнителя символ пробела).

С учетом сказанного оператор может выглядеть следующим образом

```
String operator ++( int )
{
    String dsn( *this );

    if ( this->length != 0 )
    {
        size_t n  = length + 1;
        char *tmp = new char[ n + 1 ];

        std::memcpy( tmp, this->s, this->length  );

        tmp[ length ] = tmp[ length - 1 ];
        tmp[n] = '\0';

        delete [] s;

        this->s = tmp;
        this->length = n;
    }

    return dsn;
}
```